# How to use gganimate over two datasets which depend on one another

Tags: r, gganimate

As the title suggests, I would like to animate over two datasets.

The first, is quite simple:

```
dots <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~time,
  1, 1, 1,
  1, 2, 2,
  2, 2, 3,
  2, 1, 4, 
  1, 1, 5
)

anim <- ggplot(data = dots, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_time(time) +
  ggtitle("Frame: {frame_time}")

anim
```

This produces the following exciting animation:

[image: first animation]

As you can see, the dot moves along according to the time dimension in the `dots` tibble, the cardinality of which is 5. I'd like for a box to appear when `time == 2` and when `time == 4`.

If I modify the code, I can get the boxes to appear statically:

```
boxes <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~id, ~timeb,
  0.9, 1.9, 1, 2,
  1.1, 1.9, 1, 2,
  1.1, 2.1, 1, 2,
  0.9, 2.1, 1, 2,
  0.9, 1.9, 1, 2,
  1.9, 0.9, 2, 4,
  2.1, 0.9, 2, 4,
  2.1, 1.1, 2, 4,
  1.9, 1.1, 2, 4,
  1.9, 0.9, 2, 4
)


anim <- ggplot(data = dots, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_time(time) +
  ggtitle("Frame: {frame_time}") +
  geom_polygon(data = boxes %>% filter(id == 1), mapping = aes(x, y), fill = NA, colour = "black") +
  geom_polygon(data = boxes %>% filter(id == 2), mapping = aes(x, y), fill = NA, colour = "black")

anim
```

Which produces this animation:

[image: second animation]

So, essentially, I want the box to appear when the dot gets close.

I wouldn't want the boxes to simply flash, I'd like them to fade in and out, something like:

[image: third animation]

which I produced as follows:

```
anim_2 <- ggplot(data = boxes, mapping = aes(x, y, group = id)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = NA, colour = "black") +
  transition_states(id) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

anim_2
```

I hope that this makes sense (and that someone has a good idea for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example here: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/wiki/Tracking-of-hurricanes-and-typhoons

Note that the two geoms (line and point)each refer to a dataframe which includes the column `time`.  In principle this could have been two different dataframes, as long as they both share the same named column for the time dimension.

This means that you can have `transition_time` animate multiple geometries "independently".  You'll just need to play around with the timings of the appearance and disappearance of your boxes to get them to show up just in time for the dots.